# Serverinfo shows the wrong number of bot in the guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm actually making a server-info command in which I have a part for members count.

I want to get the number of bots present in the guild. I get no error when I execute the command with my bot but the number I get is wrong.

Here is my code for that purpose :

```js
async execute(interaction) {
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(interaction.member.displayHexColor)
        .setDescription(`**Informations**`)
        .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
        .addFields(
            {
                name: ":bookmark_tabs: **Informations**",
                value:
                `
                Guild name : ${interaction.guild.name}
                Owner : <@${interaction.guild.ownerId}>
                Creation : ${moment.utc(interaction.guild.createdAt).format("LL")}
                
                `
            },
            {
                name: ":leaves: **Guild users**",
                value:
                `
                Members : ${interaction.guild.memberCount - interaction.guild.members.cache.filter((m) => m.user.bot).size} 
                Bots : ${interaction.guild.members.cache.filter((m) => m.user.bot).size}

                Total : ${interaction.guild.memberCount}
                `
            }
        )
        .setFooter(`Commande effectuée par ${interaction.member.user.username}`, interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: 'true'}));

        await interaction.reply({embeds : [Embed]});
```

I run the command on two guilds. In the first one I have 3 bots and the command only returns 1 and in the second one I have 12 bots and the command returns only 8

And the bot has the administrator perm in both guilds

Also it doesn't give me the right number of members

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the cache, try to fetch the members first using [`members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager).

```js
async execute(interaction) {
  let members = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
  let bots = members.filter(m => m.user.bot);
  let users = members.filter(m => !m.user.bot);

  const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(interaction.member.displayHexColor)
    .setDescription(`**Informations**`)
    .setThumbnail(interaction.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .addFields(
      {
        name: ':bookmark_tabs: **Informations**',
        value: `
              Guild name : ${interaction.guild.name}
              Owner : <@${interaction.guild.ownerId}>
              Creation : ${moment
                .utc(interaction.guild.createdAt)
                .format('LL')}
              `,
      },
      {
        name: ':leaves: **Guild users**',
        value: `
              Members : ${users.size}
              Bots : ${bots.size}

              Total : ${interaction.guild.memberCount}
              `,
      },
    )
    .setFooter(
      `Commande effectuée par ${interaction.member.user.username}`,
      interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: 'true' }),
    );

  await interaction.reply({ embeds: [Embed] });
}
```

Comment: It indeed worked with the fetch method, thanks !